# Handling ContentType Relations with Doctrine/Bolt EM

Tags: doctrine, silex, bolt-cms

I have an extension serving a route which creates an entity (a question), which has a related entry (each entry has 0, 1, or many associated questions).

I can't seem to get bolt's save/doctrine's persist methods to actually persist relationships. I've tried the following:

```
$question = $repo->create([
    'question' => $request->get('question', 'What is love?'),
    'status' => 'draft',
    'entries' => [$entry]
]);
```

`$question->relation->add($entry)`

`$question->setRelation(new Collection\Relations([$entry], $em))`

(edit) I've also tried

```
$entry = $em->find('entries', $request->get('entry', 1));
$related = $em->createCollection('Bolt\Storage\Entity\Relations');
$related->add(new Relations([
    'from_contenttype' => $question->getContenttype(),
    'from_id' => $question->getId(),
    'to_contenttype' => $entry->getContenttype(),
    'to_id' => $entry->getId()
]));

$question->setRelation($relation);
```

per a response below, but that still doesn't work.

None of which work - it correctly saves the Question (Content) entity, but not the relation. Not really sure where to go from here...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working test I have, I know the syntax is ugly at the moment, the plan is to add some more helper methods, but this does work.

```
$repo = $app['storage']->getRepository('pages');

$newPage = $repo->create(    
    [
        "title"  => 'An Example Title',
        "slug" => 'an-example-title',
        "status"  => 'published',
        "teaser"    => 'An intro teaser goes here',
        "body"  => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectet adipisici.',
    ]
);

$newPage->getRelation()->setFromPost(['entries' => [1]], $newPage);
$repo->save($newPage);
```